# javascript Date creates strange date when days are greater than what is in the month

Tags: javascript, date

I have an input form where the user can choose a date from a calendar, however I also wanted them to be able to type in the date manually

the function validateDate() is called when the user clicks out of the input box

```
    //Make sure valid date is entered into the field, otherwise throw back an error
function validateDate(date) {
    var dateObj = new Date(date);

    console.log(dateObj.getDate());

    if (dateObj == "Invalid Date") {
        dateWrongFormat(false);
        return false;
    }

    return dateTimeToString(dateObj, true);
}
```

problem is: say if the user types in something by accident like "55/02/2014" it converts to "02 Jul 2018" instead of displaying that it is an invalid date (note: this is 4 years past the year they entered).

Is there are simple way to check if the days or month is invalid this or do I have to create my own date-checking system?

EDIT: so it seems like no matter what I type in, it believes it a valid date - even formatting with moment.js. Thanks for the help guys but I have to write my own for this one!

Comment: This is the designed behavior for date. Check the MSD docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Date.parse. If you do `Date.parse("55/02/2014")`, it returns NaN.

**UPDATE**
Something like this-

```
 <script>
    function validateDate(date) {
        var datems = Date.parse(date);

        if (isNaN(datems)) {
            dateWrongFormat(false);
            return false;
        }else{
        var dateObj = new Date(date);
        return dateTimeToString(dateObj, true);
        }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: simple and built-in, what could be better?

Comment: Hrmm this doesn't seem to be working - it just gives me the millisecond format anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Isaac - but everything I do refuses to work and states the date as valid. The client is 'very particular' on how they want it to work so I'm going to implement my own validation methods as it also seems to convert YY '15' to '1915'. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing stuff with dates, you may find using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) helpful.

In particular, if you construct a moment instance from a string, you can then ask it if it is valid:

```
moment('55/02/2014').isValid(); // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function validateDate(date) {
//Format = dd/mm/yyyy
var day=date.split("/")[0];
var month=date.split("/")[1];
var year=date.split("/")[2];
var dateObj = new Date(year, month-1, day);

console.log(dateObj.getDate());

 if ((dateObj .getMonth()+1!=month)||(dateObj .getDate()!=day)||(dateObj .getFullYear()!=year)) {
        dateWrongFormat(false);
        return false;
    }

    return dateTimeToString(dateObj, true);
}
```